# Converting a python dictionary key pair into string

Tags: python

I am new in Python, I have a python dictionary as shown below

```
{"details":[{"name":"akhil","account":"ABCD"},{"name":"rahul","account":"GCOD"},{"name":"rakesh","account":"ABCD"}]}
```

Need to convert this dictionary into a python string as shown below. One more point this dictionary is dynamic, so it should be a little generic.

```
ABCD -
akhil
rakesh
GCOD -
rahul
```

Thanks in Advance, Any help will be appericiated.

Comment: Did you know that rakesh would answer you question in advance or it is a coincidence, that names in your example match? :D

Comment: Now we just need some Rahul to edit the question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple iteration.

```
data = {"details":[{"name":"akhil","account":"ABCD"},{"name":"rahul","account":"GCOD"},{"name":"rakesh","account":"ABCD"}]}

result = {}
#Group name by account!. 
for i in data["details"]:
    result.setdefault(i["account"], []).append(i["name"])

for k, v in result.items():
    print("{} -\n{}".format(k, "\n".join(v)))
```

**Output:**

```
ABCD -
akhil
rakesh
GCOD -
rahul
```